# How to control the order of overlays on an Android MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

Say there are two overlays on a MapView. How do I specify which appears on top of which?

Comment: How do you create the overlays? Are you using RelativeLayout? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one that you add second will be drawn on top of the first one. Simple as that.

Comment: That's kind of a shame. I'm having to remove an overlay and re-add it, to get the ordering right, but all works now via myMapView.getOverlays().remove(...)

Answer (score 3):

When mapView.getOverlays() is called it returns a List which is ordered from lowest layer (index 0) to the highest layer to be rendered. When adding a new Overlay you can call:

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(location, Overlay);
```

The location value determines the z-index. So, for example, if I wish to add a new layer and push it to the bottom I could pass an index of 0. No need to remove and re-add overlays to fix their order.